# How to partition by a varying expression in windows functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a table that looks like this:

table : **user_histories**

| user_id | start_at | value | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 88 | company_id |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | 169 | Company_Id |
| 189 | 2021-12-03 | 142 | company_id.id |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | walmart | company_name |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | target | Company_Name |
| 189 | 2021-12-03 | whole foods | company_id.name |

This table defines how uses change companies. The company associated has a company id and a company name. This table holds data for multiple users and the attributes vary in the way described in the table.

Ideally I would like to write a query with the following results.

| user_id | start_at | value | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 88 | 2021-03-02 |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | 169 | 2021-12-03 |
| 189 | 2021-12-03 | 142 | null |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | walmart | 2021-03-02 |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | target | 2021-12-03 |
| 189 | 2021-12-03 | whole foods | null |

Of course I would be close to accomplishing this by writing:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
start_at,
value,
LEAD(start_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, attribute ORDER BY start_at) AS end_date
FROM
user_histories;
```

But the attributes vary even though the attributes of `company_id`, `Company_Id`, and  `company_id.id` all mean a change in company_id. Is there anyway I can use regex to match to this specific pattern?

I am using Snowflake. Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE user_histories(
  user_id int,
  start_at date,
  value varchar,
  attribute varchar
);

INSERT INTO user_histories VALUE
(189,2020-12-12,88,'company_id'),
(189,2021-03-02,169,'Company_Id'),
(189,2021-12-03,142,'company_id.id'),
(189,2020-12-12,'walmart','company_name'),
(189,2021-03-02,'target','Company_Name'),
(189,2021-12-03,'whole foods','company_id.name');
```

Comment: You can also do just based on start_at, unless start_at for two different companies is same.

Comment: The fact that you are considering regex makes me suspect  your sample data is not representative? does user_histories contain attributes that contain values other than company ie key value pairs and is that why you are considering regex?

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the data inconsistency in the `attribute` column as I doubt there's any "silver bullet" for that. Below I propose a case expression to make that column consistent before using it in the over clause:

```
with CTE as (
    select
          user_id
        , start_at
        , value
        , case
               when lower(attribute) like '%company%name%' then 'company_name'
               when lower(attribute) like '%company%id%' then 'company_id'
               else lower(attribute)
          end as attribute
    from user_histories
    )
select
      user_id
    , start_at
    , value
    , LEAD(start_at,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, attribute ORDER BY start_at) AS end_date
from CTE
```

**result**

```
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
| user_id |  start_at  |    value    |  end_date  |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
|     189 | 2020-12-12 | 88          | 2021-03-02 |
|     189 | 2021-03-02 | 169         | 2021-12-03 |
|     189 | 2021-12-03 | 142         |            |
|     189 | 2020-12-12 | walmart     | 2021-03-02 |
|     189 | 2021-03-02 | target      | 2021-12-03 |
|     189 | 2021-12-03 | whole foods |            |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

see: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28c517d6375aef5702c432396c235213)*